# How to pass parameters from controller to serializer in FastJsonAPI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, json-api, ruby-on-rails-5.2, fastjsonapi

I have a controller method `drop_down_values` in which I select a set of values and respond in json ,building the object using a serializer. I am using FastJson Api. I want to know , how can I access other variables present in the controller in the serializer.

```
def drop_down_values   
    @drop_down_values = IndustrySectorList.all
    @values = @drop_down_values.pluck(:industry_sector)
    render json: DropDownValueSerializer.new(@drop_down_values).serialized_json
end
```

I need to use the `@values` variable in the serializer. How can i pass this to serializer? I am not able to directly access this variable in the serializer.

Serializer:

```
class DropDownValueSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :id
  end
```

Stack & version -

1. Rails - 5.2.1
2. Ruby - 2.5.1
3. FastJsonAPI - 1.5

Comment: This should cover you use case: https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi#params

Comment: @DennyMueller I tried the params section but it did not work. I can find examples in serializer, I need to know how it is passed from controller and then accessed in serializer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do but a serializer is usually a resource. In your case you can pass params into your drop down serializer :

```rb
DropDownValueSerializer.new(movie, {params: {values: @values}})
```

```rb
class DropDownValueSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :id

  attribute :values do |drop_down_value, params|
    params[:values]
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you should use the serialized method like this: 
`render json: DropDownValueSerializer.new(@drop_down_values).serialized_json`

Comment: that was copied here wrongly. now corrected. However the issue still persists

Comment: What's in DropDownValueSerializer?

Comment: I see two `end` on the serializer. Could you share what's actually the error you are getting?